# How vxlan0 of container's overlay network goes outside the real world?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm

Hi dear stackoverflowers,

I would like to understand how the vxlan0 interface of docker overlay namespace can go outside the network namespace of this overlay network?

I found a start of answer on slide 39 of this slidedeck: 
https://fr.slideshare.net/lbernail/deep-dive-in-docker-overlay-networks

"*Vxlan must created in host namespace and moved to overlay namespace, otherwise vxlan could not interact with outside*"

But it's a little bit lighter as explanation... I red man of ip link and few document about network namespace, but i did not find anything relevant...

Thanks to enlight me!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your steps on how to bring up the overlay networks?

When I using OVS, I do the following:

1. Create a OVS switch on host1(192.168.1.181)， name ovs-br2.

```
ovs-vsctl add-br ovs-br2
```

2. Then add a port into ovs-br2. telling it there is an interface vxlan0 used as an overlay interface， talking to outside world IP 192.168.1.180. Make sure 192.168.1.180 pingable at your host.

```
  ovs-vsctl add-port ovs-br2 vxlan0 -- set interface vxlan0 type=vxlan options:remote_ip=192.168.1.180
```

3. Go to host2(192.168.1.180) do the same two things above, change only ip point to host1. the overlay network is set up between host1 and host2.